# What Dual CPU Processors are compatible with my Dell T7400 workstation /

Tags: processor

I have a Dell T7400 Workstation currently running on the following specs:
*Dual Intel Xeon E5410 @ 2.33 GHz
32 GB RAM
Windows 10*

The machine is working great but the processor and RAM performances are maxed out when I am rendering a complex After Effects composition. I'm considering to upgrade the processors but I have no idea how to know what processors are compatible with my machine. Do I just look for any processors that runs on the same socket " LGA771" , or there would be another criteria to judge upon.

Here are the full specs list for the Dell T7400 :
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/precn/en/precn_t7400_specsheet.pdf

Comment: As this question currently stands I can see that basically what you need help with is knowing which particular processors you should upgrade to, but your wording makes it sound like a technical support question about system compatibility, which we don't cover here. Reword your question and we can answer without fear of wasting our time.